# Took Long Time to Build Next.js Monorepo with Seperate Test Packages

Tags: next.js, monorepo, turborepo

I'm using Turborepo for my Next.js Project. Following [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bsE1VJn1HeU) test-suite setup for seperating the test components package with the next.js app. But when i build the app, it making the build time took much longer time compared to not seperating the package. After deep delving into this issue, turns out it caused by the test packages node_modules. Whenever i delete the test packages node_modules the build time is become normal again. I already try to exclude it via ts.config and next.config but it wont resolve the build time problem. Is it expected like this or how can i resolve the build time anomality since the test packages dependent with the next.js app?

Already configured ts.config to exclude node_modules folder and ignore it in webpack next.config.